# Posting to linkedin group not as promotion

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

We have been using the SNAP Wordpress plugin (http://www.nextscripts.com/social-networks-auto-poster-for-wordpress/) to auto post to a LinkedIN Group successfully for some months, but all of a sudden, these posts are now marked as "promotions" within the group so are not visible as normal discussion posts.

Does anyone know if the LinkedIN API has changed the way that the posting to a group discussion is handled, which may have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn has changed their API lately, you should head to their website and check it out at https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, but couldn't see any specific changes that would be causing this?